# Use cycle value to compare with list

Tags: django, django-templates

I've faced some problems with compare value in list

Let's say I have list of values such as [u'1', u'2', u'3']

And If I write it in template like this:

```
{% if "3" in selected_list %}

Checked

{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

Then It works well

But If I try to use it in cycle like:

```
{% for item in items %}

{% if item.id in selected_list %}
Checked
{% else %}
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Then it fails, it doesn't compare them together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert it to string, because you have list of strings
Or you can convert items in list to integers in view like that

```
selected_list = [int(item) for item in selected_list]
```

And then it would be working
P.S. u'8' stands for unicode string
P.P.S forget to mention that your item.id is integer